# How do I backup my wordpress template through Filezilla?

Tags: wordpress, backup, filezilla

I made changes to a wp template and I need to export it. I can't seem to drag and drop my template folder through filezilla. I tried allowing permissions for every thing but nothing seems to work. Am I missing a step or is there another way?

Comment: *"I can't seem to drag and drop my template folder through filezilla"*: Please be more specific about the problem you are facing. Anyway, please move your question to [su]. It's [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here.

Answer (score 0):

You can try a few things with filezilla. First, try reconnecting to the server you are pushing your file to. If that doesn't work, see if you are able to move other files between the two servers. If you end up needing to, you may want to use another program such as Dropbox, Google Drive, or Github to back up your work.

Comment: i tried reconnecting but still no luck. I can drop files into my ftp but I cant drag things out. this is strange because I remember dragging files out before.

Answer (score 0):

there are other ftp clients you could try. like the (s)ftp commands on linux. this is also one way to see if the problem is with filezilla or something else.